# urban airship production versus development program name

Tags: android, urbanairship.com, package-name

I am trying to learn Urban Airship.  Seems pretty easy, right?  Well.  I only have two questions that I can't seem to answer.

First I have set up everything in development under my userid.  It works great sending messages to my phone.  Awesome! 
But when I go to create one for Production, I get an error saying duplicate package name.  I am not using my own userid for this, though.  I am using the clients userid.  They also have the Apple version set up in development and production.
Why am I getting this error?  Could it be that I am trying to use the same package name under two different userids?

Second question is when I put my app to production, do I change the assets folder called airshipconfig.properties  to have an entry inProduction = true?  I have entered all the other applicable fields.

Thanks very much for you help. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the production and non-production versions must both be under the same id in urban airship.  eg.. You cannot have production version under Debra and have a non-production version under Tony.  They must both be under Debra or under Tony.

You must change the asset folder called airshipconfig.properties to "inProduction=true".